How to install VPN on Linux Debian so that it could be used by built-in Windows 10 client?
What is the nowadays approach to install VPN on Linux Debian so that it could be used by built-in Windows 10 client?
I found the question What VPN server can I install on linux and connect to on Windows through its builtin VPN client?, but it is 10 years old and refers to the products (like openswan) which is no longer supported on Linux.
With the server:

Linux Wonderland 4.19.0-25-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.289-2 (2023-08-08) x86_64

And clients on Windows 10 how to install the VPN so that Windows 10 build-in client (without installing additional software) could be used?

StrongSwan seems to be the current IPSec contender, particular if you're Debian based

@ChrisDavies, thanks. So, in this case the Setup L2TP IPSEC VPN on Ubuntu guide is relevant or there is a better way/guide to setup VPN in my case? I am just looking for most simple and straightforward way to do so.

IME IPSec is neither simple nor straightforward

@ChrisDavies, so what would be the recommended way to solve the initial task?

I'm not entirely sure, so I've not written a proper answer. Me, I'd use OpenVPN or Wireguard, but you asked for a solution that could leverage the built-in VPN and I've not tried that
